What is the High-Water Mark settings in the CycloneDDS config, and when should I care?
In the CycloneDDS readme on github I noticed this statement in the runtime customization section:

WhcHigh determines when the sender will wait for acknowledgements from the readers because it has buffered too much unacknowledged data. There is some auto-tuning, the (current) default value is a bit small to get really high throughput.

What exactly could be the consequences of a too small value? Frequent message loss on remote receivers? Could it affect additional local subscribers, too?
Does this affect reliable and best effort connections in the same way?
Should I expect this to become relevant only when the network seems saturated (or even before)?
It seems 500kB is the default value (https://github.com/eclipse-cyclonedds/cyclonedds/blob/master/docs/manual/options.md#cycloneddsdomaininternalwatermarkswhchigh). (Or, isn't it?)
What would be a good value for an application that has some high-throughput topics (e.g., camera images and pointclouds)? How should I proceed to choose a good value?
